# Having trouble with WebStorm, ERROR: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webstorm

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js" --ignore-existing create-react-app .
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Amir'
command not found: create-react-app
Done
```

I've just created a new project in WebStorm and I get the error message above.

I have no clue how to fix it and would appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a space in your user name... It's a [known issue](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146) with npx, you will face similar problems when creating your application in terminal, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512 and https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9091, for example. See https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146#issuecomment-384019497 for possible workaround

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to fix it by using the link for the workaround by creating a directory junction to my users folder that didn't have a space in it. You can run a command like this in an administrative powershell:

cmd /c mklink /J "C:\Users\myname" "C:\Users\My Name"
You can then use this junction as if it were your real user directory:

npm config set cache C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
npm config set prefix C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: fine, thanks for letting me know. Could you accept my answer, please?